# SQL, comparing two values and returning values that don't match

Tags: sql

i'm running a sql statement that reads values from two different databases and returns records that do not match.
The two fields i'm trying to compare are:

- `NAME_TYPE` which is a `number` eg. 1 or 2
- `PartyType` which is `varchar` eg. Person/Organisation

How might I compare this effectively?

Most of them have been easy to compare like `NAM.NAME <> cl.ClientName`.

But I'm finding this a bit more difficult, new user to sql so any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? name_type 1 = partyType person? or?..

Comment: sorry yeah, name_type =1 party_type = person I need to compare these

Comment: But I mean, how do we know which name type equals which partyType ? also.. post you current attempt

Comment: there is only two type, person is equal to 1 and organisation is equal to 2..

Comment: I need to compare thousands of records and see if there is any inconsistencies

Comment: And whats the result you want to get? I'm having it hard to write you a query that I dont know what to select

Comment: i want the sql statement to return any fields that don't match, so if a row has a name_type = 1 and party_type = organisation

Comment: select NAM.NAME,cl.Client from table1, table2 where name_type = 1 and party_type != organisation or name_type=2 and party_type != person

Comment: It isn't clear what links table1 to table2. Please post sample data.

Comment: select
NAM.NAME_TYPE,
cl.PartyType
from CUSTOMER cst
INNER Join NAME NAM ON CST.CUST_NO = NAM.ID_NO AND NAM.RECORD_OBSOLETE_DATE IS NULL
inner join [MI_DW2].[dwh].[dim_client] cl ON cl.ClientNumber = convert(char(10),cst.cust_no)
where
(NAM.NAME_TYPE = 1 and cl.PartyType <> 'Person') and (NAM.NAME_TYPE =2 and cl.PartyType = 'Organisation')

Comment: sorry about formatting

Answer (score 0):

This may work;

```
   WHERE NOT ((NAM.NAME_TYPE = 1 and cl.PartyType = 'Person') OR (NAM.NAME_TYPE =2 and cl.PartyType = 'Organisation'))
```